# Hibernate with Liquibase

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm, liquibase

I have an application that is using hibernate to create the initial database using annotation.

I did like to be able to update the database automatically when adding/editing a class. I release you're not meant to use hibernate update as this is not safe for production.

After hours of googling I can see that people have looked at using liquibase to generate a changeLog from hibernate metadata.

However, most of these questions/posts are years out of date. The one plugin I could find has virtually no documentation.

Has anyone done this, if so please tell me how. Or an alternative at least. Do all ORM updates have to be manually created with sql scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current documentation for the liquibase-hibernate plugin is at https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki

It will let you compare your hibernate model and the database and create and/or append to a changelog so you do not need to edit the XML manually. What do you find missing from the docs?

Comment: For me, the documentation didnt work. My questions is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892826/generate-changelog-with-liquibase-and-jpa-entities